# Proper answer to 「何名様ですか」

Tags: word-choice

I have a question about how to properly answer a question.

At restaurants, the hostess will often ask 「何名様ですか」 ("How many in your party?")

For example, if you have four people in your party, is it proper to reply 「4名です」?
Or is 「4人です」 better?

Comment: Just hold up a few fingers and grunt

Answer (score 13):

There is no difference between 4人です and 4名です.

You may say the word as you like.

Comment: The first result on Google for "何名様ですか" was that only "バカ" use "4名です" (a racist post, so I'm not going to link to it). I'm curious why the writer of that post thinks so. 
However, I'm not convinced 名 is an honorific; many other answers in Japanese (like on Yahoo) say either is fine, just like your answer.

Comment: I saw the post now but almost Japanese don't think so and 名 is not honorific. 様　is a honorific. If you reply like 4名様です,　it is wrong.

Comment: Your answer definitely matches with what I've seen used; Japanese friends often say "4名です" at restaurants. 

It's interesting that one source that user snailboat found says 名 is honorific. Most sources seem to indicate, though, that 名 is simply formal if anything.

Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 5):

According to [the article](http://www.nhk.or.jp/kininaru-blog/55095.html) from "[トクする日本語](http://www.nhk.or.jp/kininaru-blog/)" by NHK, 人 is used when you just count the number of people whereas 名 is more used in a formal expression or when there is a fixed number.

`「人{にん}」＝【単純{たんじゅん}に人数{にんずう}を数{かぞ}える場合{ばあい}】、「名{めい}」＝【改{あらた}まった表現{ひょうげん}をする場合{ばあい}、定員{ていいん}･定数{ていすう}のある場合{ばあい}】とまとめることができそうです`

Therefore, restaurants wouldn't ask you "何人様{なんにんさま}ですか". As a customer "４人" is more appropriate since "４名" sounds a bit formal and objective. Although, nowadays people don't really mind whether "４人" or "４名" is used in response.